# Why acceleration is positive in this graph?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, differentiation

[image]

Please explain this graph to me as why acceleration is positive

Comment: There is a rule that tells us the function is convex if its second derivative is greater than zero. 

$a=\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ and it is greater than zero, so $x$ is convex. 

Another explanation: the acceleration is positive, then the velocity $v(t)$ is an ascending function; we could consider an elementary case, when $V=ax$, i.e. $a$ is constant. Then $x\sim Ca^2, C>0$, so the path would represent a part of parabola with "branches up".

Comment: @nicael I think your answer is fine and if I were you I wouldn't have deleted it. If you would like to undelete it I think it would make a useful contribution. This is an elementary question but I still think it's a valid question. We were all beginners at some point.

Comment: @John well, ok!

Answer (score 3):

The velocity is the gradient of the line on your position:time graph. If I roughly estimate the gradient by eye I get something like this:

[image: Gradients]

And the acceleration is the gradient of the velocity:time graph

Comment: Alternatively, the velocity is increasing (becoming less negative) with time, so the acceleration must be positive.

Comment: Please tell me why velocity is increasing?

Comment: @brahamdeepsingh The velocity starts out as a negative number and it becomes less negative. That means the change in the velocity is a positive number i.e. the velocity is increasing.